# Comparing string in Python: String X is ASCII, and String Y is UTF

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, ascii, string-comparison

I have a rather weird problem:
How do I compare strings (using Python ) that where String X is ASCII and String Y is in UTF or Unicode?

Currently, when I am comparing strings, I receive the following issue:

```
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  filteredtext = [t for t in s if t.lower() not in stopwords]
```

How do I ensure that the strings are in the same format?

Best Regards.

Comment: There's no such thing as "UTF".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert all string using the underlaying encoding and compare them:

```
print unicode(s1, 'ascii') == unicode(s1, 'utf-8')
```

Comment: Unicode is not the "underlying encoding" of ASCII. It's more like a least common multiple.

Comment: "underlaying encoding" = encoding used for the related byte stream